# How to (simply) connect Python to my web site?

Tags: python, web

I've been playing with Python for a while and wrote a little program to make a database to keep track of some info (its really basic, and hand written). I want to add the ability to create a website from the data that I will then pass to my special little place on the internet. What should I use to build up the website? After dabbling with Django, I've found it overkill and over my head, but if that's the only option I'll learn to use it.

Does anyone know an easy way to output a database of arbitrary format to one or more HTML (or different format) files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would generate a page or two of HTML using a template engine ([Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/2/) is my personal choice) and just stick them in your `public_html` directory or wherever the webserver's root is.

Comment: +1, simple and addresses the main issue. Can schedule the generation with cron to keep it updated.

Comment: yeah. +1, keep simple what's simple

Comment: Agreed, although I use Cheetah <http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/> for the template engine.

Answer (score 0):

Generating static HTML is great, if that works for you go for it.

If you want a dynamic website and the ability to update, [web.py](http://webpy.org/) might work for you. Simpler than Django and stand-alone (although just about everything I start in web.py eventually gets rewritten as a Django app...)